# Characterization of point on the boundary vs point on the relative boundary via sequences

Tags: general-topology, analysis, convex-analysis

Let $X \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be a convex set. Now consider the statement

$$ x \in \mathrm{cl}(X)\; \backslash \; \mathrm{int}(X).$$

In this case, I am assured that there are two sequences, say $a_k \in \mathbb{R}^n \; \backslash \; \mathrm{cl}(X)$ and $b_k \in X$ such that
$$\lim_{k\rightarrow \infty} a_k = \lim_{k\rightarrow \infty}b_k = x$$

Now consider
$$ y \in \mathrm{cl}(X)\; \backslash \; \mathrm{relint}(X).$$
Here $\mathrm{relint}(X)$ is the interior with respect to the affine hull of $X$.
In this case, is it correct to say that there again exist sequences
say $c_k \in \mathbb{R}^n \; \backslash \; \mathrm{cl}(X)$ and $d_k \in X$ such that
$$\lim_{k\rightarrow \infty} c_k = \lim_{k\rightarrow \infty}d_k = y$$

Comment: Both $\overline{X}$ and $\operatorname{ri} X$ are subsets of $\operatorname{aff} X$, so the problem reduces to the first one if you consider the restriction to the affine hull.

Comment: @copper.hat Could you explain in an answer? I ask because  at this link https://maunamn.wordpress.com/1-convex-separation/ there is a formal proof of this. I wasn't sure why the case with relint(X) needs a proof.

Comment: Note that $X^\circ \subset \operatorname{ri} X$.